# Function that multiplies all numbers between "a" and "b" with do loop

Tags: homework, scheme, mathematics

I'm making a function that multiplies all numbers between an "a" input and a "b" input with `do` loop. If you please, check my function and say what's wrong since I don't know loops very well in Scheme.

```
(define (pi-function x y)
  (let ((result y))
    (do ((limI x (+ x 1)))
        ((= limI y) result)
      (set! result (* result limI)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `do` loop without using `set!`.

```
(define (product-of-range x y)
  (do ((result 1 (* result i))
       (i x (+ i 1)))
      ((> i y) result)))
```

Comment: But that doesn't work, when I call (product 1 3) it returns 3, but it should return 6. That function only multiply x for y. What should do, f.e. (product 1 3)
(* 1 2)
(* 2 3)

Comment: @gn66: It returns 6 for me. Notice that I updated the function.